# Detect last plugin in a placeholder

Tags: django-cms

Is there a way to detect the last (or first) plugin that has been placed inside a placeholder?

I want to add a class="last" to my plugin template in case of the last plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a try:

{% if plugin.last %}
   This is the last plugin for current placeholder
{% endif %}

(plugin.first should also work)

Comment: Do you know how this works? Is plugin a django-cms keyword? I can't find documentation about it. Thx

Comment: plugin is not a keyword. it is probably the `instance`, i.e. the plugin instance itself.