# Django- CMS: Plugin position in a placeholder

Tags: django-cms

I was looking for a way to check the plugin's position within a placeholder in Django-CMS. I found this question [Detect last plugin in a placeholder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5543947/detect-last-plugin-in-a-placeholder)

Is "plugin" a django cms keyword? I can't find documentation about it.

My question is: How can I obtain information about the plugins rendered within a Placeholder?

Thanks

Comment: Here is the [code](https://github.com/divio/django-cms/blob/develop/cms/models/pluginmodel.py#L317) of the CMSPlugin model. As you can see it does define some helpful methods to know where it resides in it's placeholder. These kinds of methods are not documented, but reading the source code will reveal them :)

Comment: thanks Paulo. I'll take a look of that code to answer my question

Comment: @joseS have you resolved this? I tried to sum up Paulo's comment in a real answer, adding the essentials from the link he provided, so others can benefit from it more easily...what do you think?

Answer (score 2):

if you don't override your plugins render method (2.4 and up), you'll have your plugin as `instance` in your context. using the following, you'll get the 1 based position of your plugin:

`{{ instance.get_position_in_placeholder }}`

also interesting: `is_first_in_placeholder` and `is_last_in_placeholder`. in fact, @paulo already showed you the direction in his comment ;) this is the code, with new line number: https://github.com/divio/django-cms/blob/develop/cms/models/pluginmodel.py#L382

Comment: It looks like this includes the child-plugins of the plugins in the placeholder as well? If so, is there any way to only get the position of the plugins directly in the placeholder?

Comment: With a quick test on django-cms 3.2 I cannot confirm this behaviour. Nested plugins all get their own (1-based) position right. Which version are you on?