# Django-CMS: get_position_in_placeholder in top-level plugins only?

Tags: django, django-cms

I just found out that it is possible to get the position of a plugin in a placeholder tag via `instance.get_position_in_placeholder` in django-cms templates ([thanks to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12977863/django-cms-plugin-position-in-a-placeholder)).

But it seems that if those plugins have child-plugins, then they are counted towards the position as well. Example:

```
placeholder
  -- plugin  # pos: 1
    -- child_plugin # pos: 2
    -- child_plugin # pos: 3
  -- plugin # pos: 4
    -- child_plugin # pos: 5
  -- plugin # pos: 6
```

What I'm looking for is a counter, that only counts the plugins that are direct children of the placeholder. Example:

```
placeholder
  -- plugin  # pos: 1
    -- child_plugin # ignored
    -- child_plugin # ignored
  -- plugin # pos: 2
    -- child_plugin # ignored
  -- plugin # pos: 3
```

I use a placeholder tag to render the plugins:

```
{% placeholder general_content %}
```

And the child-plugins are rendered with `{% render_plugin plugin %}`.

The django-cms version is 3.1.3.

And here is a screenshot of the unwanted behavior in the DOM (2 and 4 are child-plugins):

[image]

Is there such a method or property available in django-cms templates?

Comment: how do you render your child plugins? Are they embedded in a TextPlugin, or "real" child plugins, rendered with `{% render_plugin plugin %}` the render_plugin tag? in my tests, the ones you want `# ignored` get their own, 1-based index/position?

Comment: also, django-cms version used??

Comment: Thanks for reaching out, I just updated the question with the information.

Answer (score 1):

This is strange, as what one would expect is the following:

```
placeholder
  -- plugin_with_children # pos: 1
    -- child_plugin # pos: 1
    -- child_plugin # pos: 2
  -- plugin_with_children # pos: 2
    -- child_plugin # pos: 1
  -- plugin # pos: 3
```

I can confirm this works for me as shown just above, with django-cms 3.1.3 and 3.2. So, this might be an issue with the definition of `child_plugin`? my child plugins that get correct positions are either rendered in a `TextPlugin`, or in a forloop, like this (in the template of `plugin_with_children`):

```
{% for plugin in instance.child_plugin_instances %}
    {% render_plugin plugin %}
{% endfor %}
```

I suspect your children are not real children? ;-)

If they are: There is a management command, that fixed issues with the old MPTT plugin/page tree (did you update from 3.0?), maybe the error lies somewhere there. The "position" is in the db, so you might need to check your database directly. Also, re-adding the content could help (just to be sure, watch the db, etc...).

Comment: I render them exactly the same way (with a forloop). So this might be a problem with the `child_plugin` definition? Is there anything in specific I need to do (or not do) in that definition?

Comment: a child plugin would be one, if you render it with the {% render_plugin %} tag. So I guess they are real children then, but your database might be messed up. did you update from 3.0? (see http://docs.django-cms.org/en/develop/upgrade/3.1.html , bottom, the fix-mptt)

Comment: No, I didn't upgrade. But I'll rebuild the tree anyway, I hope that will help :)